# CSS Class inside media query not applying

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm currently trying to make a website more responsive, and that via media queries. However, for some reason I can't get my classes to at all apply inside my media queries (or at least, that's what it seems like?).

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, overlooking something, or if it's simply a sign on that I should take a break. Either way, the CSS looks as following:

```
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    font-size: 56px;

    :not(.aboutUs_extra_margin) {
      margin-top: 190px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are missing a class that's supposed to be wrapping the styling. The styling will be applied to the class that you wrapped around the styling. Your code is supposed to look like this:

```
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    .className{
        font-size: 56px;
    }

    :not(.aboutUs_extra_margin) {
         margin-top: 190px !important;
    }
}
```

If you want all your classes to apply this styling you can add body instead. Body is the parent element of all classes.

```
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    body{
        font-size: 56px;
    }   
    :not(.aboutUs_extra_margin) {
         margin-top: 190px !important;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Based on the comments below I have made a fiddle containing the media queries. One inside a parent element and one outside it.

https://jsfiddle.net/rhbsqj6z/4/

The only styling that applies is from this code:

```
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    body{
        background:green;
    }   
    :not(.aboutUs_extra_margin) {
         border:1px solid red;
    }
}
```

While you'd expect the styling below it to apply, since CSS looks at the last defined styling. Also if you would comment out the first media query, you can see that the one below will still not work:

```
.parent{
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    body{
        background:red;
    }   
    :not(.aboutUs_extra_margin) {
       border:1px solid blue;
    }
}
```

The media queries inside a parent class are not working.

Comment: Oh, that much I know, since I far up in the code have a parent container as well. But it seems like the "margin-top: 190px !important;" part is *still* being applied to .aboutUs_extra_margin

Comment: @Xariez  Do you have a code fiddle where we can test this on? :)

Comment: @Xariez, did you also try putting the media queries outside the parent elements? As far as I know media queries should be outside elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, that'll be quite difficult, since it's built through a Wordpress Page Builder and this is merely custom CSS.

Comment: I might consider that, but seeing how the properties are still applying, except for the :not()-line, I feel like it wouldn't exactly fix it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200188/discussion-between-xariez-and-it-girl).